# PHP - having trouble getting a java exec to execute when I curl to the file containing it

Tags: java, php, curl, exec

I've currently been trying to figure this out for 16 hours straight, and I can't seem to figure it out! When I execute the file with the java-exec directly, it executes fine, but when I curl to said file and try to echo it (the java file returns an int if that makes a difference) back to the file which curled, the java exec does not execute at all!

My curl is your average php curl which includes

```
$db = curl_init();
curl_setopt($db,CURLOPT_URL,"example.com/exec.php");
curl_setopt($db, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$dbexec = curl_exec($db); 
curl_close($db);
echo $dbexec;
```

and my java exec within 'example.com/exec.php' is

```
$exec = exec("java example '$arg'");
echo $exec;
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try to echo not `exec` result, but `output` argument. `$exec = exec("...", $out); echo $out;`

Comment: @kaduev13 that doesn't fix the issue unfortunately, the $out isn't echoed unless I execute the file directly. The issue lies within the fact that the exec isn't executing when I curl to it.

Comment: you can debug it using `curl_error` php function call just after `curl_exec($db)`.

Comment: @kaduev13 nothing gets echoed with the curl_error. the thing is, the curl'ed php file executes fine (say i have 'echo "hello";' at the bottom of exec.php, it'll echo "hello" just fine). its just that the java exec wont initiate for some reason

Comment: ok, what about an `$arg` argument. How do you getting it?

Comment: Try this `exec("java example '$arg'", $output, $status); var_dump($status); `, status of the executed command will be written to this variable.

Comment: @zstate i get var_dump(0) when i execute the file directly (when it executes correctly) and var_dump(1) when i try to curl to the exec.php file. what does this mean?

Comment: @jameslin zero exit status usually success, non-zero exit status is a failure.   Try to use very simple java file like [helloWorld](https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/11hello/) and see if the problem is in your java example file.

Comment: @zstate yeah, i tried that :/ it doesnt even execute "exec("javac example.java");" --- i'm starting to think its a server sided problem